# Confusing MySQL Join Tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I need help building a mysql query to join a few tables. I've been staring at it for a while now, attempting different ideas, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

I have two tables:

```
1) TASKS
- id
- name
- description
- date_added
- status


2) T_USERS_ASSIGNED
- id
- task_id
- user_id
```

The first table holds tasks and the status of them. The second table holds what user is assigned to them. As a single task can have multiple users assigned to it so there could be multiple records in the T_USERS_ASSIGNED for a single task.

I'm trying to count all the tasks that are assigned to a specific user where the status of the tasks is equal to 1.

I tried something like this which failed. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated:

```
SELECT `p_tasks_assigned`.`id` as `users`
 FROM
 `p_tasks_assigned` JOIN
 `p_tasks` ON `p_tasks_assigned`.`task_id` = `p_tasks`.`id`
WHERE `p_tasks`.`status` = 1 ANND `p_tasks_assigned`.`user_id` = :user;

$result = $db->prepare (statement above);
$result->bindValue (':user', $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result->execute ();
$count_user_open = $result->rowCount ();
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's just a typo on SO but you misspelled one of your `AND` statements.

Comment: Do you get any error message? If yes, posting it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT a.user_id
     , COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) AS count_tasks_assigned
  FROM t_users_assigned a
  LEFT
  JOIN tasks t
    ON t.id = a.task_id
   AND t.status = 1
 GROUP BY a.user_id
 ORDER BY a.user_id
```

---

That gets all users.  If you want to return just a count for a single user, and you pass in the user_id as a bind parameter (as I just noticed in your example), then:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) AS count_tasks_assigned
  FROM t_users_assigned a
  LEFT
  JOIN tasks t
    ON t.id = a.task_id
   AND t.status = 1
 WHERE a.user_id = :user
 GROUP BY a.user_id
 ORDER BY a.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you are a looking for a list of users and then next to that user's name would be a number of tasks with a status of 1. Since multiple users can be assigned to a task the sum of these numbers could be greater than the number of tasks. If this is the case your query would look like:

```
SELECT user_id, 
       Count(*) AS count 
FROM   t_users_assigned 
       LEFT JOIN tasks 
              ON t_users_assigned.task_id = tasks.id 
WHERE  status = 1 
GROUP  BY user_id;
```